# Set values of column in dataframe according to the order of another column value in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like below:

```
df={'NAME':['a','b','c','d','e'],'COUNT':[25,23,14,19,2]}
pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['NAME','COUNT'])
```

[image]

I want to set of values of column 'color' according to 'COUNT' column values which are in order or may be not in order like

[image]

```
colors=["rgb(211, 63, 106)","rgb(233, 154, 44)","rgb(232, 195, 60)","rgb(226, 230, 189)"]
```

The first four values of colors should set upto 4th max row value, rest of other rows should fill with `"rgb(226, 230, 189)"`. But struggling to set this format. I am new to python and I have tried with 'apply' function, but how to find nth max value within apply?

```
df['color']=df.apply(lambda row:"rgb(211, 63, 106)"  if row.COUNT.max() else "rgb(226, 230, 189)")
```

Comment: do you mind explaining more what your intent is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we create a dictionary of the top four values with the first four values in your color list - then we map these to your dataframe and fill any blank values with your target.

```
colors = ["rgb(211, 63, 106)","rgb(233, 154, 44)","rgb(232, 195, 60)","rgb(226, 230, 189)"]
map_colors = dict(zip(
            df.sort_values('COUNT',ascending=False).iloc[:4]['COUNT'].values,
            colors)
                )
```

---

```
print(map_colors)

{25: 'rgb(211, 63, 106)',
 23: 'rgb(233, 154, 44)',
 19: 'rgb(232, 195, 60)',
 14: 'rgb(226, 230, 189)'}
```

---

```
df['Colors'] = df['COUNT'].map(map_colors).fillna('rgb(226, 230, 189)')


  NAME  COUNT              Colors
0    a     25   rgb(211, 63, 106)
1    b     23   rgb(233, 154, 44)
2    c     14  rgb(226, 230, 189)
3    d     19   rgb(232, 195, 60)
4    e      2  rgb(226, 230, 189)
```